# Can't use Json() in asp.net core web api as it in asp.net core web

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In asp.net core web I create a controller and I can use:

```
return Json(new {status=true});
```

but in asp.net core web API I can't do it.

In a controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
        public JsonResult Get(int id)
{

}
```

I can not return `Json()`

How to use it?

Comment: Hi @liang.good Did my answer help you resolve your issue?

Comment: I am afraid not.return Ok(new {state=true}) is the answer

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net Core Web API does provide support for wide varieties of response types, with Json being one among them. You can do that like shown below. Make sure you have all your required dependencies. You can learn about the dependencies from the documentation link I attached in this answer.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Json(model);
}
```

You can also specify strict response formats using the `[Produces]` Filter on your controller.

#### Configuring Custom Formatters

You can also configure your own custom formatters in Asp.Net Web API project by calling the `.AddFormatterMappings()` from `ConfigureServices` method inside of your `Startup.cs`. This allows for a greater control on your content negotiation part and lets you achieve strict restrictions.

Please go through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.1) documentation to understand further.

#### Using Responses with Status Codes

However, when using Web API, I suggest you use the helper methods that are built in so that your response becomes more expressive as it contains both the response content along with the status code. An example of how to do that is below

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok(_authors.List());
}
```

For a full list of helper methods available, you can take a look at the [Controller.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Controller.cs)  and [ControllerBase.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs) classes.

Comment: Is the Ok(_authors.List()); returns which contenttype "application/json" or "text/plain"?

Comment: It's going to be JSON as long as you're not specifying otherwise. JSON is the default format used by ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net core web api inherit from [`controllerBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-3.1), which doesn't contain a Json(Object) method. You should initialize a new JsonResult yourself in the action.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public JsonResult Get(int id)
{
    return new JsonResult(new { status = true });
}
```